# Wordpress Google Maps (API) on admin side

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

On my wordpress website i had Google maps that showed the error : "Oops! Something went wrong.".

**I fixed it on the wp-content side** by adding my key to a google maps enqueue_script in functions.php .

But i have the same problem on the admin side now . See photo https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u7VU.png

Comment: Open console, copy all errors and paste here.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ix8g9Pt.png

In the frontend it's working after setting the key in functions.php

Comment: Have you tried to add API key?

Comment: I added the API key in functions.php and i repaired the maps visible to the visitors (/wp-content).



My problem now is in the wp-admin (administration area). I have a map here aswell and i don't know where to add the api key script . 


I tried in /wp-admin/admin_header.php (with <script>tags) and also in /wp-admin/load_scripts.php with wp_enqueue_script (the same i did in functions.php)

Comment: In `functions.php` file you need to add action: `add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'function_name' );` 'function_name' is function where you added `wp_enqueue_script();`. More info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts